# open source implementations of the blue/green deployment pattern

Tags: deployment

Martin Fowler defines blue-green deployment here: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html

The general idea is that website deployment is done by creating an independent instance of the site, and only redirecting customer traffic to that instance after it has been fully prep'd and verified.

I wonder what open source code is out there that uses a blue-green deployment implementation. I am looking for reference implementations, preferably in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the link/name.  I've done deployments like this for a long time but always had to explain the entire thing to people.  Cool to know I'm not alone and that there is a name multiple people use to refer to the style.  I've always built my own tools to manage switching between environments though(usually via load balancer config changes).

Comment: I've always heard of this as blue/gold deployment but the same principles.

Comment: any final solution about it ?

Answer (score -1):

You repoint your DNS/router/load-balancer to get to the correct backend. That's about as dead-simple an operations task as you can get (and entirely dependent on your implementation.)

Thus, i can't recommend any products, because I'm not entirely sure what you're really looking for.